# Reading from a Flux<Integer> in chunks

Tags: java, project-reactor, flux, reactive-streams, backpressure

Is it possible do read from a webflux flux in chunks? ( other than using delayElements )

For example after I write

```
Flux.range(1, 10).doOnNext(System.out::println).take(5).subscribe();
```

is there any way to continue to read the next 5 integers?

If not, is there an alternative for the consumer to decide when to request the next piece of data?

Edit:

**To clarify, I would like to read the first 5 values, then pause until an arbitrary later time in the program, then read the next 5 values without recreating the emitter flux. simply calling buffer() won't do**

Comment: Do you mean something like `Flux.buffer()`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some kind of diagram, how you want to read the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 from the example `range()` you have build in your application.

Comment: This example code does not help. You are talking about reading the first 5 values, then pause, then read the next 5 values, but your example build an observable with 3 values in total and you read it with two separated subscriptions. This doesn't add up, it makes no sense of what you are trying to accomplish. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description and/or diagram of how you want to read the data.

Comment: Have you looked into a `buffer(int)` or `window(int)`? This way you won't have the value emitted until events are gathered to that group. So, then you may apply your delay after such a group is released.

Answer (score 2):

then you need a full-fledged asynchronous subscriber object, not just a chain of methods.

```
// use maven dependency 'org.df4j:df4j-core:8.3'
import org.df4j.core.dataflow.Actor;
import org.df4j.core.port.InpFlow;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public class FluxSubscriberTest {

    @Test
    public  void test10() {
        FluxSubscriber subscriber = new FluxSubscriber();
        Flux.range(1, 10).subscribe(subscriber.inp);
        subscriber.start();
        boolean ok = subscriber.blockingAwait(5000);
        Assert.assertTrue(ok);
    }

    static class FluxSubscriber extends Actor {
        InpFlow<Integer> inp = new InpFlow<>(this, 5);
        int count = 0;

        @Override
        protected void runAction() throws Throwable {
            if (inp.isCompleted()) {
                System.out.println("input stream completed");
                complete();
                return;
            }
            Integer value = inp.remove();
            System.out.println("value="+value);
            if (++count==5) {
                count = 0;
                System.out.println("pause:");
                delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, it reads 5 items first, and then one by one after each call to `inp.remove()`. If this is not exactly what you want, then you can extend class `InpFlow` to modify the policy when it invokes `Subscription.request()`.

Source codes are avalable at https://github.com/akaigoro/df4j (yes I am the author).

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` is the keyword you're looking for

```
Flux.range(1, 10)
            .buffer(5)
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .subscribe();
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#buffer--

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear. The point was to continue reading the next 5 at an arbitrary point later in the program.